# Name for a set of elements that fully determine a morphism

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

In a concrete category (i.e., where the morphisms are functions between sets), I define a **base** of an object $A$ to be a set of elements $M$ of $A$ such that for any morphisms $F,G:A\to B$ that coincide on $M$, we have $F=G$.

**Question:** Is there an established name for a **base** in that sense?

**Examples:** In the category of vectors spaces, generating sets are bases. In the category of sets, $A$ is the only base of $A$.

**Note:** The above definition does not really need a concrete category (an initial object is enough), but I decided to formulate it in a concrete category for simplicity.

Comment: Surely for vector spaces, but also in general: what a bout "a spanning subset" or, as you suggested implicitly, "a generating set"?

Comment: Doesn't 'generating set' fit your requirements? I see no reason to invent anything fancier.

Comment: I'm not sure generating set is really accurate. In general, this might not be the same as a "base". E.g., in the category of unital homomorphisms between algebras. A generating set of $\mathbb C$ would probably be $\{1\}$, yet a base of $\mathbb C$ would be $\varnothing$. Also, I'm not looking for a new term, I wonder about established terminology.

Comment: You don't need to put the identity in as a generator for unital algebras.  It's part of the signature.

Comment: Another example why generating set does not fit: In the category of topological space with continuous functions, a "base" would be a dense subset. I don't think one would usually say that the dense subset "generates" the space.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg If you use that convention, then consider the category of unital algebras with (not necessarily unital) homomorphisms. A generating set of $\mathbb C$ is $\varnothing$ but $\varnothing$ is not a base. My point is that generating is, in general, something else.

Comment: If you allow nonunital homomorphisms then 1 is not part of the generating set because you are just working in the category of not necessarily unital rings and so you would have to include it as a generator. But then I'd don't think 0 would be a base because you can map $\mathbb C$ to itself by the zero map and the identity and these both agree on zero and are  X- algebra homomorphisms in the nonunital sense in that f(cx)=cf(x) for all complex numbers c.  But you have to define your morphisms clearly

Comment: I was working in the category of **unital** algebras with nonunital homomorphisms. According to *your* definition of a generating set in a category of unital algebras (your first comment), a generating set of $\mathbb C$ is $\varnothing$. Yet $\varnothing$ is not a "base" as you also say in your second comment. So base and generating set are not the same thing in this category.

Comment: In the category of unital algebras with non unital morphisms empty is not a generating set.  When I said 1 was part of the signature then I was assuming homomorphisms preserve 1. Unital rings with non unital homomorphisms doesn't fit the framework of universal algebra.  1 is not part of the signature and so you have to include it in the generating set.

Comment: Notice there are no free objects in the category of unital algebras with non unital maps so you have to be careful what generators mean and the correct interpretation is generates as a non unital ring

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124294/discussion-between-dominique-unruh-and-benjamin-steinberg).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The term "base" should not be used, since, as you say, you are actually generalizing the notion of a generating set.

It is an **epi-sink**, also known as **jointly epimorphic family**. See [Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf), Definition 10.62 and (dual of) Definition 10.5. A family of morphisms $(f_i : A_i \to A)$ is called an epi-sink when for $u,v : A \to B$ we have $\forall i (u \circ f_i = v \circ f_i) \implies u=v$. When the coproduct $\coprod_i A_i$ exists, this means that we have an epimorphism $\coprod_{i \in I} A_i \to A$.

If you have a terminal object $1$, morphisms $1 \to A$ are called global elements, and we can look at epi-sinks consisting of global elements of $A$.

For many categories, though, global elements are not enough. When we have a forgetful functor $U$ to $\mathbf{Set}$ with a left adjoint $F$, we have $U(-) \cong \hom(F(1),-)$, so that elements of the underlying set can be seen as morphisms on $F(1)$, and we can talk about epi-sinks on $F(1)$.

But the most general form does not put any restrictrions on the domains at all.

Comment: +1, but “jointly epimorphic family” is a much more common term for this than “epi-sink”, at least in my experience.

Comment: This is true (I have added it), perhaps also because "jointly monomorphic family" is much more common than "mono-source" (as defined in Joy of Cats), since "source" already has a different meaning in category theory.

Comment: There is no Definition 10.26 in the linked Joy of Cats. Maybe it's a typo in the number?

Comment: Yes I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the context of von Neumann algebras, *separating* is used for this concept. Confer [Takesaki], Definition II.3.16 (slightly reformulated):

**Definition.** Let $\mathcal M$ be a von Neumann algebra on $\mathfrak H$. A subset $\mathfrak U$ of $\mathfrak H$ is called *separating* for $\mathcal M$ iff for all $a\in\mathcal M$, $a\xi=0$ for all $\xi\in\mathfrak U$ implies $a=0$.

(But note also the definition of a *separating set* in [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator) which is related by a different concept.)

[Takesaki] *Takesaki, Masamichi*, Theory of operator algebras I, New York, Heidelberg, Berlin: Springer-Verlag. VII, 415 p. DM 79.00; $ 44.30 (1979). [ZBL0436.46043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0436.46043).